# How can I make sure the values are aligned and the format is consistent when exporting csv into Word?

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, docx

I created this dataframe that I export as a csv file, and then I want to import it into a word doc. My issue is that when I import it into word, the formatting gets messed up and the columns don't match their respective values anymore.

**How can I make sure the values are aligned and the format is consistent when imported in Word?**

```
    Target                    Something        Something_long        Something _even_longer
0   Targetttt                   2.037                2.016                  1.010
1   Targetttttttttttttttttt     2.016                2.008                  1.004
```

here's the code so far:

```
df.to_csv(r"C:\Users\crist\word_automation\Summary_template\TABLE.csv", sep='\t', encoding='utf-8', index = False)

import docx 
import csv

doc = docx.Document()
with open('TABLE.csv', newline='') as f:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f) 

    csv_headers = next(csv_reader)
    csv_cols = len(csv_headers)

    table = doc.add_table(rows=2, cols=csv_cols)
    hdr_cells = table.rows[0].cells

    for i in range(csv_cols):
        hdr_cells[i].text = csv_headers[i]

    for row in csv_reader:
        row_cells = table.add_row().cells
        for i in range(csv_cols):
            row_cells[i].text = row[i]

doc.add_page_break()
doc.save("data.docx")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a very crude solution for this:

1. In each column find the value with the maximum amount of characters used. For example in column 1, of the data you shared, it is `Targetttttttttttttttttt` which is `23` characters.
2. Now add blank space to every other value in that column till it's 23 characters. Example: In column 1, add `17` blank spaces to `Target`, and add `14` blank spaces to `Targetttt`.

This way all your values will have the same width, and hence be aligned.

Comment: it's self-explanatory but if you want I can add some code too.

Comment: Is there a way to get the value of the maximum amount of characters in each column? My table will take different values so the number of characters is not consistent. @Sumant Agnihotri

Comment: again, a crude way would be to loop over each column and check the length and save max length. Then loop over the column again and add blank space so that each value in the column has the same number of characters. something like this: `target              
  `  `Targetttttttttttttttttt`

Comment: I see. I'll try to do that. Thanks

Comment: Any suggestions on how to do that?